# MySQL Update with PHP variables in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I've been stuck on this for an hour.

I've got a series of variables ($recordsQuestion_1, $recordsQuestion_2, etc). Since the total number of these variables changes, I want to update my DB in a loop. However, I can't figure out how to actually store the variable. Just $l or "recordsQuestion_1 (2, 3, etc)" into the DB.

Here's what I've got, tried grasping variable variables (not even sure if that's how to do it), but couldn't get anything to work. Maybe an array?

Suggestions?

```
$l = 1;
while ($l <= $num_rows) {
    $query = "UPDATE records SET recordListingID = $recordsQuestion_" . $l . " WHERE recordID = " . $l;
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $l++;   
};
```

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. Use mysqli or PDO and prepared statements instead. Prepared statements are more efficient when executing a query multiple times. Also, prepared statement parameters aren't vulnerable to SQL injection; no need to escape values and no worry that you'll forget.

Comment: Outputting database error messages to non-admin users [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). Instead, log the MySQL error message. For some errors (such as those related to missing or invalid values), output your own [error message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TP10) to the user and what action the user can take to address it. For the rest, inform the user that there was an internal error.

Comment: As for [`or die`, don't use it if you're outputting HTML](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want use someting like this:

```
$var1 = "foo";
$i = 1;

echo "${"var$i"} boo"; //foo boo
```

Why don't you just use array instead of the series of variables?

Comment: Yup this worked. Thanks! Tried pasting the updated code but it didn't work :( I'm probably going to switch to an array, this is being posted dynamically with jQuery. I'll probably have to change to .serializeArray

Comment: `$l = 1;
 while ($l <= $num_rows) {
  $temp = "${"recordsQuestion_$l"}";
  mysql_query("UPDATE records SET recordQuestion = '$temp' WHERE recordID = $l");
  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $l++; 
 };`

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to have an varying number of variables (`$recordsQuestion_1`, `$recordsQuestion_2` ... `$recordsQuestion_n`), look at using an [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) instead, as this will be far easier to work with.

Which could then result in a cleaner loop like:

```
$recordsQuestion = array(
  'Zero' , # PHP Arrays are zero-indexed, so the first element will have a key of 0
  'One' ,
  'Two' ,
  ...
);

$sqlTpl = 'UPDATE records SET recordListingID = "%s" WHERE recordID = %s';
foreach( $recordsQuestion as $key => $value ){
  $sqlStr = sprintf( $sqlTpl , mysql_real_escape_string( $value ) , (int) $key );
  if( !mysql_query( $sqlStr ) ){
    # Row Update Failed
  }else{
    # Row Updated OK
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I found the solution below, and I'll change to an array. I'm going to try using .serializeArray (posting with jquery)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, your case would be:

```
$l = 1;
while ($l <= $num_rows) {
    $query = "UPDATE records SET recordListingID = " . ${"recordsQuestion_$l"} . " WHERE recordID = " . $l;
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $l++;   
};
```

However, it occurs to me your problem may be to do with SQL. You can't have a variable number of columns in standard SQL. To store a variable number of things, like you're suggesting, you can use an additional column to represent the number you're calling $l. For instance,

```
recordId | questionId | questionText
---------+------------+-------------
       1 |          1 | "Why?"
       1 |          2 | "Who?"
       1 |          3 | "When?"
       1 |          4 | "How?"
       2 |          1 | "How long?"
       2 |          2 | "Which?"
       3 |          1 | "Wherefore?"
       4 |          1 | "Really?"
```

In this case, each recordId can have a different number of questions.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's what the loop would look like using PDO, with a little more error handling added:

```
$updateRecords = $db->prepare('UPDATE records SET recordListingID = :listing WHERE recordID = :id';
$failed = array();
try {
    foreach ($questions as $id => $listing) {
        if (!$updateRecords->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':listing' => $listing))) {
            # record failure message
            $failed[$id] = ...;
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    # DB error; handle it
    ...
}
```