# Page loads for a very long time upon submitting page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Just got this code working after a couple hours of frustration. I know I'm mixing MySQLI and PDO, but that's just to get everything working - I'll be converting everything to PDO before release. This is a dispatching webpage for my volly fire department.

For some reason, when I click "submit", taking me to page two to run these commands, it'll load for about 2 minutes before it runs the command.

Here is the response:

**array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "0004" ["id"]=> string(4) "0004" } 
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 608 bytes) in /home/rhapidfyre/public_html/sasd/supervisor.php on line 765**

Line 765 is the HTML Form code towards the bottom, for "supervisor.php"

```
if($_GET['call'] == "close")
{
    if($_GET['callid'])
    {
        if($_GET['page'] == 'two')
        {
            $callid = $_GET['callid'];
            $closing = $_POST['closing'];
            $query = "SELECT id FROM engaged WHERE callnum = '$callid'";
            $getunits = $link->query($query);
            $unitsrow = $getunits->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

            var_dump($unitsrow);

            $doit = $db->prepare("UPDATE incidents SET closing = :closing, closer = :myname, active = 0, archive = 1 WHERE id = :callid");
            $doit->bindParam(':callid',$callid);
            $doit->bindParam(':myname',$myname);
            $doit->bindParam(':closing',$closing);
            $doit->execute();

            $doita = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM engaged WHERE callnum = :callid");
            $doita->bindParam(':callid',$callid);
            $doita->execute();

            for($i = 0;$i < count($unitsrow);$i++) {
                $doitb = $db->prepare("UPDATE logins SET assigned = '0' WHERE id = :unitnum");
                $doitb->bindParam(':unitnum',$unitsrow[$i]);
                $doitb->execute();
            }

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "supervisor.php?finished=closecall"</script>';
        }
        else
        {
            $callid = $_GET['callid'];
            $prep = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM incidents WHERE id = :callid");
            $prep->bindParam(':callid',$callid);
            $prep->execute();
            $prepresult = $prep->fetch();
            ?>
            <form action="supervisor.php?do=func&call=close&callid=<?echo $_GET['callid'];?>&page=two" method="POST">
                <font color="#FF0">You are closing call #: </font><font color="#FFF"><strong><?echo $_GET['callid'];?></font><br />
                <font color="#FF0">Incident Type: </font><font color="#FFF"><strong><?echo $prepresult['type'];?></font><br />
                <font color="#FF0">Incident Loc : </font><font color="#FFF"><strong><?echo $prepresult['location'];?></font><br /><br />
                <font color="#FF0">CLOSING NOTES:</font><br/>
                <textarea rows="6" cols="60" name="closing" /></textarea><br />
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT!">
            </form>
            <?
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $callzactive = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id,priority,type,location FROM incidents WHERE active = 1");
        ?>
        <font color="#FF0"><strong>SELECT CALL NUMBER</strong></font><br />
        <select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
        <option>SELECT</option><?
        while($callsactive = mysqli_fetch_array($callzactive))
        {
            ?>
            <option value="supervisor.php?do=func&call=close&callid=<?echo $callsactive['id'];?>"><?echo "#".$callsactive['id']." (".$callsactive['priority'].") ".$callsactive['type']." @ ".$callsactive['location'];?></option>
            <?
        }
        ?></select><?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why assume that this portion of your code is causing this?  It says it runs out of memory on that line but maybe the memory gets filled anywhere above the code you show us.

Comment: Prior to adding the for loop, it ran flawlessly, except that it didn't run the for loop, meaning it wasn't updating logins to set assigned to 0. Everything else ran perfectly.

Comment: I forgot to mention - The code works when there is only one unit assigned. It changes assigned to zero and everything works, without any delay. If there are two or more units assigned, assigned zero does not run and it delays.

Comment: That doesn't change the error message you show in your question which is not related to the script's duration, although the duration could be linked to the reason it runs out of memory.

Comment: The only thing that makes sense to me, is that the loop won't stop, which makes me suspect "$i < count($unitsrow)", so I will keep playing with that...The secondary problem to this issue is that when I add multiple units, it counts a maximum of 2 people, but repeats the last row found for both rows.. So if I assign A B and C, it'll detect 2 rows, and say that both rows found are C C.

Comment: I think that part of your confusion comes from the `MYSQLI_BOTH` but there is most likely many other things to improve in your code.

Comment: Eliminating BOTH and replacing it with ASSOC gave me the response of the last unit in the list which was 0004, and using NUM gave me the response of the first unit which was 0003, and the var_dump for my process returns NULL, but eliminating BOTH stopped the long loading.

Answer (score -1):

Try for the sake of testing remove the update query in for loop

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($unitsrow);$i++) {
    $doitb = $db->prepare("UPDATE logins SET assigned = '0' WHERE id = :unitnum");
                                    $doitb->bindParam(':unitnum',$unitsrow[$i]);
                                    $doitb->execute();
}
```

Not the speed-wise solution in general. Prepare the statement before for loop. As in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116059/2558156) in another question.

Comment: This doesn't solve OP's problem and would at the very best be useful as a comment.  Stick to questions you can answer directly until you have sufficient reputation to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into that. I tried it out but I still get the loading error, this time from the execute line. I'll try it out later. It would seem the loop is running forever, which I suspect the "count($unitsrow)" portion for that.